# Is there a name for the distribution whose PDF is -ln(x) on its support [0, 1)?

Tags: distributions, density-function, logarithm

If so, what is its name? If not, how/where can information about it be found?

Comment: It is the pdf of the product of 2 independent standard Uniform random variables, so perhaps one could  call it the Product Uniform distribution.

Comment: Moments are not difficult to calculate.  For example it seems to have mean $\frac14$ and variance $\frac7{144}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but I've noticed that if $X$ has this density, then 
$$
- \log(X) \sim \text{Gamma}(2,1).
$$
Maybe call it a "negative log-gamma" distribution?

Edit: [these guys](https://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=3958&context=etd) call it that.

Comment: That link does not now seem to work, but it may be https://dr.lib.iastate.edu/entities/publication/39c35942-0a9c-43f2-83a9-562c12085047