# Generating MLE in python - Problem witth the function

Tags: python, maximum-likelihood, data-visualization, likelihood, computational-statistics

After my previous question ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/612405/how-to-generate-from-this-distribution-without-inverse-in-r-python/612688#612688)) I tried to improve my work with this distribution. I'm using the parametrization $$f_X(x) = \frac{\theta^2 x^{\theta-1}(\gamma-\log(x))}{1+\theta\gamma} \mathbb{I}(0<x<1), \theta \in (0, \infty), \gamma \in [0, \infty)$$ with CDF $$F(x) = \dfrac{x^\theta\cdot\left({\theta}{\gamma}-{\theta}\ln\left(x\right)+1\right)}{{\theta}{\gamma}+1}.$$  Using the answers in the post, the following functions can generate random values from this distribution:

```
def new_cdf(t, g, x):
    num = x**(t)* (t*g-t*np.log(x)+1)
    den = 1 + t*g 
    return num/den


def new_myqf(p, t, g):
    f = lambda x: new_cdf(t, g, x) - p
    res = root_scalar(f, bracket=[np.finfo(float).eps, 1-np.finfo(float).eps])
    return res.root


def get_samples(n,t,g):
    u_1 = np.random.uniform(size=n)
    x_1 = np.array([new_myqf(p, t, g) for p in u_1])
    return x_1
```

Since I wasn't able to find the maximum likelihood estimator analytically, I'm trying to do it numerically. The log-likelihood is given by $$\ell(\theta, \gamma| \mathbf{x}) = n\log\left(\frac{\theta^2}{1+\theta\gamma}\right) + (\theta-1) \sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i) + \sum_{i=1}^n \log(\gamma-\log(x_i)).$$ How can I find the maximum of this (or the minimum,  since I was told that this is the most efficient way)?

My attempt is to use the following function:

```
def MLE(n , theta, gamma):
    samples = get_samples(n , theta, gamma)
    sum_1 = np.log((theta**2)/(1+theta*gamma))
    sum_2 = (theta-1)*np.sum(np.log(samples))
    sum_3 = np.sum(np.log(gamma - np.log(samples)))
    sum = sum_1 + sum_2 + sum_3
    return sum
```

But I don't know how to find the maximum or plot it. Any help or content suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Are you aware of gradient descent and automatic differentiation? Automatic differentiation allows you to compute gradients of functions that cannot be expressed analytically, while gradient descent uses the gradient to minimize/maximize the function. Both of these can be implemented using [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/). Note that your problem will be a constrained one, since the parameters $\theta$ and $\gamma$ must be non-negative.

Answer (score 6):

I know `python` but I'm not fluent enough to provide you with a full implementation of this, so I'm showing you an `R` solution instead. I tried to make the code as self-speaking as possible.

Some comments first.

(1) From what I can see, this seems a tough likelihood surface and for numerical stability I have switched to log-parameters, i.e. I have applied a one-to-one reparametrization. The parameter vector is thus $(\log(\theta), \log(\gamma))$; see the plot of the scaled log-likelihood surface below.

(2) To locate the maximum likelihood I'm using `optim` via the L-BFGS-B method but I invite you to try other methods as well. In addition, it is also possible to supply to the `optim` the analytical gradient of the log-likelihood. This may help to get closer to the peak, but here I'm not using analytical gradients so `optim` is computing the necessary gradients numerically.

(3) The option `hessian=TRUE` is for delivering the Hessian matrix at the optimum, that is, the observed information at the MLE. This is useful towards building a suitable grid for plotting the likelihood surface.

(4) In the second figure, you see the plot of $w(\tau) = \ell(\hat\tau)-\ell(\tau)$ and the contours can be treated as approximate confidence sets for $\tau = (\log\theta, \log\gamma)$.

```
# using the neg log-likelihood
nlogL <- function(param, x_vec) {
  n = length(x_vec)
  theta = exp(param[1])
  gamma = exp(param[2])
  oo1 = n*log(theta**2 /(1 + theta*gamma))
  oo2 = (theta - 1)*sum(log(x_vec))
  oo3 = sum(log(gamma - log(x_vec)))
  return(-(oo1+oo2+oo3))
}

# (your density)
myf <- function(x, a, b) {
  num = (a+1)**2 * x**a * log(b*x)
  den = 1 - (a+1)*log(b)
  return(-num/den)
}

# (your cdf)
myF <- function(x, a, b) {
  num = x**(a+1)* ((a+1)*log(b*x)-1)
  den = (a+1) * log(b) - 1
  return(num/den)
}

# quantile function computed numerically
myqf <- function(p, a, b) {
  uniroot(function(x) myF(x,a,b) -p, 
          lower = .Machine$double.eps, 
          upper = 1-.Machine$double.eps)$root
}

set.seed(5)
# get some uniform draws
u <- runif(100)
# apply the inverse transform to get the data
xvec <- sapply(u, myqf, a = 5, b=0.99)


# pdf of the true model
> plot(function(x) myf(x,a=5, b=0.99), from=0, to=1,
     col=2, lwd=2)
```

[image]

```
# find min of nlogL (or max of logL), via optim
# note the use of hessian=TRUE
(opt = optim(par = c(0,0), fn = nlogL, x_vec = xvec, hessian=TRUE,
            method = "L-BFGS-B", 
            lower = c(-5,-10), upper = c(20,20)))

$par
[1]  1.817531 -3.987984

$value
[1] -55.46771

$counts
function gradient 
      40       40 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"

$hessian
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 198.950731 9.1942354
[2,]   9.194235 0.9039165


# the approx-variance covariance matrix of the log-params
sqrt(diag(solve(opt$hessian)))

# plot the relative log-Lik
ngrid = 200
ltheta = seq(0.8,2.2, len=ngrid)
lgamma = seq(-15,2, len = ngrid)

grid_lpar = expand.grid(ltheta, lgamma)
nlogLik_val = apply(grid_lpar, 1, nlogL, x_vec = xvec)
nlogLik_val_mat  = matrix(nlogLik_val, ncol=ngrid, byrow = F)

image(ltheta, lgamma, (opt$value - nlogLik_val_mat), 
      xlab = "log(theta)", ylab = "log(gamma)", 
      main="Plot of max(logL)-logL")
contour(ltheta, lgamma, -(opt$value - nlogLik_val_mat), 
        levels = 2*c(qchisq(0.50, df=2),qchisq(0.75, df=2),qchisq(0.95, df=2)),
        labels = c("50%", "75%", "95%"), add= TRUE)
points(opt$par[1], opt$par[2], pch=20)
```

[image]